# javascript - filter list against inner condition

Tags: javascript, filtering

I have a case that I need filter list of agents that have contracts with a specific condition (ex contract status to be approved )

how json looks like 
agent --> has an array of carrier --> has an array of contracts (I filter against contractStatus)

```
{
      agent_id: "19831225",
      agent_carriers: [
        {
          agent_id: 19831225,
          agent_carrier_id: 10462,
          carrier: "Aetna US Health Care",
          contracts: [
            {
              agent_id: 19831225,
              contractStatus: "APPROVED",

            },{
              agent_id: 19831226,
              contractStatus: "Submitted",

            }
          ]
}
```

my code

```
unfilteredAgents.forEach((agent, agentIndex) => {
    agent.agent_carriers.forEach((agentCarrier, index) => {
      const matchedContracts = agentCarrier.contracts.filter(contract => {
        console.log(searchKeys, " match With ", contract.contractStatus);
        return searchKeys.includes(contract.contractStatus);
      });
      if (matchedContracts.length > 0) {
        agentCarrier.contracts = matchedContracts;
      } else {
        agent.agent_carriers.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    if(agent.agent_carriers.length === 0){
      agent.agent_carriers.splice(index, 1);
    }

  });
```

this code show wrong data I dont what I miss 
thanks

**UPDATE my question**
I need agents with `APPROVED` only

Comment: do you want to mutate the data? please add an example data and the result after *filtering*

Comment: btw, splicing changes the index of the array. when you splice/delete a smaller index, the following indices are wrong and because you use `filter`, this given index is after splicing wrong.

Comment: Can contracts hold multiple objects and if so how to treat different contractStatus values for the filter? A more extensive example and especially a required output would be helpful.

Comment: yea I want mutate the data to extract who match this condition only

Comment: and yea contracts could hold  multiple objects  with different contracts status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach provides an array of `statuses` in order to make it more dynamic and wider.  Basically, this approach checks for every object which `contractStatus` is within the array `statuses`.

*This approach doesn't mutate the original array.*

```js
let agents = [{  agent_id: "19831225",  agent_carriers: [{    agent_id: 19831225,    agent_carrier_id: 10462,    carrier: "Aetna US Health Care",    contracts: [{      agent_id: 19831225,      contractStatus: "APPROVED"    }]  }]}, {  agent_id: "198312256565",  agent_carriers: [{    agent_id: 198312254545,    agent_carrier_id: 10462,    carrier: "Ele Agent",    contracts: [{      agent_id: 19831225455,      contractStatus: "REJECTED"    },{      agent_id: 19831225455,      contractStatus: "APPROVED"    }]  }]}],
    statuses = ["APPROVED"],
    filtered = agents.filter(({agent_carriers}) => agent_carriers.some(({contracts}) => contracts.every(({contractStatus}) => statuses.includes(contractStatus))));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
```

Comment: very nice answer but I miss mentioning that I need all agent with APPROVED status, an agent could have many contracts  with different status

Comment: could you update your nice answer to remove any agent_carrier that dosnt match

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the inner arrays and the outer as well, depending on the inner filtering.

```js
var unfilteredAgents = [{ agent_id: "19831225", agent_carriers: [{ agent_id: 19831225, agent_carrier_id: 10462, carrier: "Aetna US Health Care", contracts: [{ agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "APPROVED", }, { agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "foo", }] }, { agent_id: 99, agent_carrier_id: 10462, carrier: "Aetna US Health Care", contracts: [{ agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "fo", }, { agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "foo", }] }] }, { agent_id: "19831225", agent_carriers: [{ agent_id: 19831225, agent_carrier_id: 10462, carrier: "Aetna US Health Care", contracts: [{ agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "foo", }] }, { agent_id: 99, agent_carrier_id: 10462, carrier: "Aetna US Health Care", contracts: [{ agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "fo", }, { agent_id: 19831225, contractStatus: "foo", }] }] }],
    searchKeys = ["APPROVED"],
    result = unfilteredAgents.filter(agent => {
        var carriers = agent.agent_carriers.filter(agentCarrier => {
            const matchedContracts = agentCarrier.contracts.filter(({ contractStatus }) => searchKeys.includes(contractStatus));
            if (matchedContracts.length) {
                agentCarrier.contracts = matchedContracts;
                return true;
            }
        });
        if (carriers.length) {
            agent.agent_carriers = carriers;
            return true;
        }
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this answer doesn't filter list it returns the whole list

Comment: it does . . . .

Comment: I pass list and it should return matched agents only with your code it return the whole list , it may be need to change unfilteredAgents.forEach to filter or something return matched only but thanks for your answer